# Python: Trying to gather specific information from a website

Tags: python

Beginning programmer here. Just completed the CS61A introduction Python class @ UC Berkeley, and I was thinking of trying to implement a little program:

Basically, I want to be able to enter a band name, and have the program search www.setlist.fm, and return a bunch of setlists for recent concerts of that band. Sounds easy enough... I have a VERY basic idea with what to do with urllib and urlopen, but that's about it. Any pointers or guidance on how to get started?

Thanks!

Comment: The best [pointer](http://xkcd.com/138/) I can give is to **start** coding. You know about `urllib` and `urlopen()`, so get those bits working and then concentrate on the next part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Read about their API.
http://api.setlist.fm/docs/index.html

Read how to make HTTP GET requests using urllib2
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml